# Joomla 2.5 call component from url on a multilingual system

Tags: joomla, components, multilingual

I've developed a component on a local installed single language joomla. I'm now trying to install it on a multi language system and on that system I can not call my module from the url.

The standard URL: index.php?task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400

is being automatically translated in: index.php?task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400&Itemid=600&lang=en

and this URL results in an Error 404.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need an option=com_something in your url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Elin is correct, you're missing the component.

This means that the right component is the homepage on your development site (so it's gathered by SEF from the URL - or lack thereof since it's the root), and NOT on your multi-language site.  Simply add `&option=com_yourcomponentname`, using the component name of the default page of your development site.

This appears to have nothing to do with the multilanguage feature.

Comment: I tried "index.php?option=com_wandB&view=default&task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400" but Joomla replaces it with "index.php/en/?option=com_wandB&view=default&task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400". (It's stuffing this /en/ in between). On the local server this "index.php?option=com_wandB&view=default&task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400" works very well. Any comment?

Comment: I disable the SEF and tried again. index.php?option=com_wandB&view=default&task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400. Joomla changes the url to index.php?option=com_wandB&view=default&task=Weight_and_Balance&plane=DR400&lang=en (adding &lang=en at the end) and it gives an error 405.

Comment: In order to get rid of the default prefix you need to enable the System - Language Filter plugin and set it to Remove URL Language Code (which applies to the default language only).  Reading the original code again, is Itemid 600 correct for your menu item? Does it still appear when you turn SEF off?

Comment: Works. The other system is case senditive. That's the reason why your solution didn't seem to work. Thanks!